# SVG: generate a grid with random fill colour for each cell/rect?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg, grid, vector-graphics

Is there a way to generate an SVG grid with specified columns/rows and give each cell a different fill colour?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to think about how to create a random color. A simple solution would be using hsl colors with a random hue value.

```
function randomColor(){
return `hsl(${ Math.floor(Math.random()* 360)}, 100%, 50%)`
}
```

You can enhance the function by using also random saturation, and lightness.

Next you need a function to create a rectangle - i.e the cell of the grid. This is a function that createsa rect. The object o has all the attributes needed for the rect.

A double loop will create all the cels for the grid.

You can change the size of the cells by changing the width and the height (w and h vars). You can change the size of the grid by adding a width attribute to the svg element.

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
//size (width and height) of the cell
let w = 10,h=10;


//generate the grid
for(let y = 0; y < 100; y+= h){
for(let x = 0; x < 100; x+= w){
  let o = {x:x,y:y,width:w,height:h,fill:randomColor()};
  drawRect(o, s)
}
}

//function to generate a random color
function randomColor(){
return `hsl(${ Math.floor(Math.random()* 360)}, 100%, 50%)`
}

//function to create a new svg rect
function drawRect(o, parent) {
  let rect = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'rect');
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      rect.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(rect);
  return rect;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" id="s"></svg>
```

Comment: I produced a similar solution, but not as elegant. This is much cleaner. Thank you so much!